# ¿Cual es la forma mas practica y eficiente para validar formularios en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo PHP, y estoy ya entrando a la parte de validacion de formularios, pero miro en internet y hay muchas formas, muchas para mi demasiado complejas como para validar un formulario y excesivamente largas, me fuera de mucha ayuda si alguien puede decirme la forma mas eficiente.

Comment: Deberías agregar un código de ejemplo de lo que estás tratando de hacer. En todo caso, una pequeña observación: No hay código demasiado largo ni complejo cuando se trata de validaciones, porque no debes escatimar en temas de seguridad.

Comment: Saludos, te aconsejo que leas el apartado de cómo se debe preguntar, un saludo.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask